# How to open to a specific state when receiving a notification from Ionic push?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, ionic-framework

I successfully set up a push notification with Ionic and ios. But I want people to click the notification and go to a dynamically pass in state. And I can not figure out how to do it...
I am using a node server. First, my state step up is below:

```
.state('app.task', {
url: "/task/:taskId",
cache: false,
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "js/tasks/task-detail.html",
    controller: "browseCtrl",
  }
},
}
})
```

And in my node server, I pass in the payload as describe here: [Ionic.io Push FAQ](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-faq)

```
var payload = {"$state":"app.task", "$stateParams": "{\"taskId\": \""+ message.relatedTask +"\"}"};
request({
    url: "https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push",
    method: "POST",
    json: true,
    body: {
      "tokens": [token],
      "notification": {
        "alert": message.message,
        "ios": {
          "badge":1,
          "payload": payload
        },
        "android": {
          "payload": payload
        }
      }
    },
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(IONIC_PRIVATE_API_KEY + ":"),
      'X-Ionic-Application-Id': IONIC_APP_ID
    }
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
  })
```

And when it click the notification, it won't go to the state (just bring me back to the app). The `message.relatedTask` is logged as the current taskId. As I can see from XCode console, it logs this:

> ```
> 2015-09-30 18:12:16.488 VideoHappy[1236:403171] Msg: {"$state":"app.task","$stateParams":"{\"taskId\": \"-JzvWR67jIqyfc9JhDMb\"}","$state":"app.task","$stateParams":"{\"taskId\": \"-JzvWR67jIqyfc9JhDMb\"}","badge":"1","body":"Test Title",foreground:"0"}
> ```
>
> 2015-09-30 18:12:16.600 VideoHappy[1236:403171] $ionicPush:RECEIVED {"$state":"app.task","$stateParams":"{\"taskId\": \"-JzvWR67jIqyfc9JhDMb\"}","badge":"1","body":"Test Title","foreground":"0"}

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Sorry. I take it back what I said and I delete my comment. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The problem turn out to be where I place my $ionicPush.register as below:

```
$ionicPush.register({
    canShowAlert: false, //Can pushes show an alert on your screen?
    canSetBadge: true, //Can pushes update app icon badges?
    canPlaySound: true, //Can notifications play a sound?
    canRunActionsOnWake: true, //Can run actions outside the app,
    onNotification: function(notification) {
      // Handle new push notifications here
      console.log(notification);
      return true;
    }
  });
```

I place this code when users signup or login. So the onNotification actual won't run when the notification come in. Instead, I put this code in app.run of my app.js file as follow:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPush, $state) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        [go here instead]
    });
})
```

The key is that **you have to ensure your application always runs the push registration call**, not just signup or login or clicking a button like the Ionic demo does. I find this out via here (credit: Raymond Camden): http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/07/02/ionic-push-example-supporting-state-changes

Read that post too for other issues you might want to know before you put up your Ionic Push notification :)